# jQuery: How to addClass to elements in loop one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a stack of 10 divs with the same class 'box'. What I try to achieve:

1. After loading the page, all of the divs that are at least partially in the viewport should be visible (addClass 'visible'). Divs completely out of viewport should be invisible (opacity 0.25  just to see what’s happening).
2. When scrolling, each div should receive class 'visible' immediately after entering the bottom edge of viewport, but only the current div, not all of them.
3. After receiving class 'visible', the divs stay unchanged, they shouldn’t lose the class after leaving the viewport.

The code below does nothing before scrolling. So the first div in the viewport is invisible, regardless of the fact that it is partially (or even completely) in the viewport.
After scrolling, the script adds class 'visible' to all divs instead of only the current one just reaching the viewport.

What could be the best approach to solve the problem?

Thanks
Ralf

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".box").each(function(index) {
    if ($(".box").isInViewport) {
      $(".box").eq($(this).index()).addClass("visible");
    }
  });
});

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
div.box { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: crimson;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

div.box.visible { opacity: 1.0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) would be helpful here

```
$(".box").each(function(index) {
    var $box = $(this), // `this` is instance of .box
        isVisible = $box.isInViewport() // note this is a function!

    $box.toggleClass("visible", isVisible);
});
```

Note you were never calling the `isInViewport()` funtion

Comment: Thanks charlietfl – the fading is happening indeed one by one now. There is still the drawback of the divs losing there visibility after leaving vp again. How could I make sure they keep visiblity after receiving it once? And is there a possiblity to call isInViewport without scrolling so I can check the first divs immediately when loading the page? Something like onScroll || on Load?

Comment: Could modify this by filtering out ones with that class and only `addClass()` when appropriate   `$(".box").not('.visible'....  `

Comment: Charlietfl, your solution ist so obvious that I'm a bit embarrased about my question. I was obviously assessing the problem as so supertricky that I couldn't imagine a solution to be so easy. Thanks for your help!